# Selenium cant locate element by label

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, mousehover, webdriverwait

I am trying to locate the tool tip on my page `demo.rezi.co` on left hand side that says landlords based on the attribute label. 
I have drafted the code below.

When I run it, it says that:

> Exception in thread "main"  org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@label='LANDLORDS']"}

This is my code so far:

```
// Test Landlord Tooltip
String expectedToolTip = "This is a test";
WebElement landlord = Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@label='LANDLORDS']"));
System.out.println(landlord.getTagName());
```

Answer (score 0):

Label is not an attribute of the link, it's a child. If you really want to select the `a` by text `LANDLORDS` you would have to use something like this:

```
"//label[contains(text(),'LANDLORDS')]/ancestor::a"
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error as before even after using the above code. The HTML can be viewed at - https://demo.rezi.co/#!/tenant. Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"label[contains(text(),'LANDLORDS')]/ancestor::a"}
  (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.77)

Comment: There's a loader on the page, you need to wait until the element is present before trying to find it

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure if I have understood the *usecase* properly. However on the webpage `demo.rezi.co` you need to *Mouse Hover* over the element with text as **LANDLORDS** and then you can extract the **Tool Tip** and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import java.util.List;
  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

  public class q53216692_MouseHover {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
          ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
          options.addArguments("start-maximized");
          options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
          WebDriver Driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
          Driver.get("https://demo.rezi.co/#!/tenant");
          WebElement myElement = new WebDriverWait(Driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//label[.='LANDLORDS']")));
          new Actions(Driver).moveToElement(myElement).perform();
          List<WebElement> tool_tip_items = new WebDriverWait(Driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//label[.='LANDLORDS']//following::div[1]//div[@class='layout-column']/label[1]")));
          for (WebElement tool_tip:tool_tip_items)
              System.out.println(tool_tip.getText());
      }
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  UPFRONT
  ADVANTAGE
  ```